# Django login Error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields', this happens when i try to login

Tags: python, django

I just got an error when I try to log in. the error happens only when I add the **save method** in the User model. But when I remove the save method there is no error at all.
I want to decrease the quality of the user picture using **PIL** to load the website faster, that's why I add the save method. THANKS!

here is the user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_lecturer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures/%y/%m/%d/', default='default.png', null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)

    username_validator = ASCIIUsernameValidator()

    def __str__(self):
         return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email)

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = self.username
        if self.first_name and self.last_name:
            full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        return full_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_single', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        try:
            img = Image.open(self.picture.path)
            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                output_size = (300, 300)
                img.thumbnail(output_size)
                img.save(self.picture.path)
        except:
            pass

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.picture.url != settings.MEDIA_URL + 'default.png':
            self.picture.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

The full log of the error is here:

```
Internal Server Error: /accounts/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 61, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 90, in form_valid
    auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 132, in login
    user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 20, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'update_fields'
[06/Sep/2020 15:25:19] "POST /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 132787
```

Comment: just change your custom save method to `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` and super.save() to `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: By adding `*args` and `**kwargs` the problem is fixed, thanks Timofey Katalnikov

Answer (score 0):

*I can't comment because of reputation, sorry. But I will leave my comment here instead.*

I don't think, the code you provided shows enough to see where the error is.

Please provide context to this traceback:

```py
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 20, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
```

Also suggestion, you seem to be, manually updating `last_login` field when you can make django do it for you.

```py
    dtLastUpdate = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        editable=False,
    )
```

By setting `auto_now` to `True` (*for DateTimeField Only*). It updates the field every time the object has been modified of any field.

Anyway, I think its best to put `super().save()` after `img.save(self.picture.path)` since the operation in your `try` clause has nothing to do with the id of the object (and other such).

Executing the `save()` method earlier won't save the operation you have in `try` clause.

Comment: It shows enough. Classic case of overriding a method with signature that's incompatible with its base classes, so it gets called with arguments that it doesn't know about.

Comment: Not quite agree that the problem shows (from the code). The overridden method is from that class. The traceback doesn't seem to be the same as to what the code provides. If you saw `user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])` that was explicitly declared. Not by default if you called the superclass save method. (This is what I know so far.)

Comment: Unsupported keyword argument, means it's called from a context that assumes `update_fields` is a keyword argument. But, I'll refine that it's obvious from the code to anyone that worked with Django models for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering this in the future, Timofey Katalnikov has the correct answer in the comments. When you override `user.save()` with your custom save override, you have to pass through the `update_fields` argument. Otherwise, when you call `user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])`, your custom save function doesn't know how to handle the argument you've provided. The only argument it takes is `self`.

To correct this, change the first two lines of the function to:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and your `update_fields` argument will be properly passed via `*args` to `super().save()`.