# Creating multiple types users in django rest framework, got an unexpected keyword argument 'last_login'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn Django, and I am creating various cases just to exercise and hopefully learn something new. Suppose that I am trying to create different users and assign different permissions latter, but first lets try to create them first. I was researching last night and it is a common problem and many differnt implementations. Most common that I have seen is with student, teacher, admin. My case is similar, but instead of teacher it is Staff as staff member. Staff inherits from User, which itself inherits from AbstractBaseUser. Below is my code for each class, model and serializer.
User mode:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name','username']

    objects = UserManager()

## And user manager:
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, email):
        return self.get(email=email)
```

Model:

```py
class Staff(User):
    qualification = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    department = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=10)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'department','username']

    objects = StaffManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Staff Model Manager:

```py
class StaffManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_staff(self, first_name, last_name, email, qualification, department, password=None):
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address.')
        staff = Staff(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,
                      email=self.normalize_email(email),
                      qualification=qualification, department=department)
        staff.set_password(password)
        staff.save()
        return staff
```

And the Staff Registartion Serializer:

```py
class StaffRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
 
    class Meta:
        model = Staff
        fields = '__all__'
 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Staff.objects.create_staff(**validated_data)
```

The problem is that from the API, a field of `Last login` is created that it is not declared in models. And when I submit my form, I get this error:

```
TypeError: create_staff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'last_login'
[17/Dec/2020 15:44:43] "POST /api/auth/register-staff HTTP/1.1" 500 104579
```

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764448/django-login-error-save-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-update-fields-t) which has the similar problem, but he has a different implementation and at this point, I do not fully understand so I could modify my code to act in the same way.

P.S, I am folloing [this](https://www.beyondscale.tech/multiple-custom-user-auth-models-in-django-rest-framework) tutorial to create multiple types of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `**validated_data` has `last_login` with a value. So when you're passing in the `kwargs` of `validated_data`, it gets expanded into the function arguments for `create_staff()` but there's no slot for `last_login`.

The fix is to add `, last_login=None` to the definition of `create_staff`, and pass it along to the new `Staff` object. E.g:

```
def create_staff(self, first_name, last_name, email, qualification, department, password=None, last_login=None):
    # code cut for brevity
    staff = Staff(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,
                  email=self.normalize_email(email),
                  qualification=qualification, department=department,
                  last_login=last_login)
```

Comment: That's a long line. Make sure you scroll all the way over to see where `last_login` got added to the function definition.

Comment: Yea, it ifx my problem, thanks. But is there any way to not show the last login field from the API?

Comment: Yes. In `StaffRegistrationSerializer` you want to add `exclude = ['last_login']` to `Meta` and remove `fields = '__all__'`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366605/exclude-a-field-from-django-rest-framework-serializer for more.